# How to remove fields from a database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I click on the icon, the fields of the news that was clicked are added to the database:

```
final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

IconButton(onPressed: () async {
                          newsController.addNews(article);
                          _fireStore.collection('favoriteItems').add({
                            'name' : article.source.name,
                            'title': article.title,
                            'image': article.urlToImage,
                          });
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_border)),
```

How now, when clicking on another icon, you can delete these values ​​from the database?

```
 IconButton(onPressed: () {
                            
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_remove))
```

Comment: You might want to google at least once? see
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#removing-data

Comment: Yes, I looked. But I don't understand how I can delete values ​​without specifying the document name each time because they are different. And so that it itself determines the name of the document when clicked

Answer (score 1):

First, get your **ID**

Then, Write this Lines:

```
 IconButton(onPressed: () {
          CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('favoriteItems');

          Future<void> deleteItems() {
            return users
                .doc('itemsID')
                .delete()
                .then((value) => print("Items Deleted"))
                .catchError((error) => print("Failed to delete Item: $error"));
          }
        }, icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_remove))
```

Comment: Is it possible to do deletion without strictly specifying the document ID? To have the ID determined automatically

Comment: No, you must specify the ID. Firebase has no idea of which document to delete. You should find a way to pass the id of the `favouriteItem` you want to delete to your `IconButton`.